# How to change CKEditor styles dynamically via script?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I a project I work on we need to restrict users with predefined styles that can be changed by the user.

In my [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/radek/7L1m4fje/21/) the function `setStyle()` works. You can try out by uncommentting the `setStyle([])`. It seems to me that I can use the `config.stylesSet =`  [assignment](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-stylesSet) only once.

The function to change the style does not work after a button click nor after setTimeout.

Is there any way to set styles via a script in CKE4 more than once?

```
CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add( 'my_styles', [
    // Block-level styles
    { name: 'Blue Title', element: 'h2', styles: { 'color': 'Blue' } },
    { name: 'Red Title' , element: 'h3', styles: { 'color': 'Red' } },

    // Inline styles
    { name: 'CSS Style', element: 'span', attributes: { 'class': 'my_style' } },
    { name: 'Marker: Yellow', element: 'span', styles: { 'background-color': 'Yellow' } }
] );

CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add( 'my_styles2', [
    // Block-level styles
    { name: 'Default Title', element: 'h2', styles: { 'color': 'Red' } },

    // Inline styles
    { name: 'CSS Style', element: 'span', attributes: { 'class': 'my_style' } },
] );



var ckeditor = CKEDITOR.inline('editor1', {
      removePlugins: 'exportpdf,sourcearea',
      fillEmptyBlocks : false,
    });
    
//    setStyle([])
    
     setTimeout(() => { 
       console. log("resetting styles")
       setStyle([])
     }, 5000);
    
    function setStyle(style){
    
//      ckeditor.config.stylesSet = style  
CKEDITOR.config.stylesSet = style
     // console.log(ckeditor)
      console.log(style)
   
   }
```